# Keymap define key not working for evil mode

Tags: key-bindings

I have read multiple posts on this site to try and solve this issue.

I am trying to define an evil key to nil. Like this:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "S-k") nil))

or

(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "S-k") nil))
```

My goal is to reassing `S-k` to `windmove-up`. However, when I press `C-h k` and then `S-k`, it says that `S-k` is bound to `evil-lookup` found in the `evil-motion-state-map`.

But even after a reset this key no not unbound.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know why your 'define-key's don't work. But have you tried `evil-global-set-key`?

Comment: Would I be testing that inside the (define-key...) part?

Comment: No, see https://evil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keymaps.html#elispobj-evil-global-set-key

Comment: The first comment was just a (quick) suggestion but you did not provide feedback about the results. Anyway, I have added a correct answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use capital `K` instead of `S-k` as follows

```lisp
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "K" nil)
```

or nicer (I think)

```lisp
(evil-global-set-key 'motion "K" nil)
```

If you place it after activating `(evil-mode)` then there is no need to use `with-eval-after-load`.